# How to filter by service groups in the monit web frontend?

Tags: monitoring, monit

Monit has a feature called "service groups" (https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-GROUPS). It allows you to filter by groups using the CLI. But is it possible to use this filter on the web frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Webfrontend does not handle groups, but is available via the CLI with "monit -g NAME COMMAND" for some commands.

Comment: I just stumbled across these lines in the source code, which seem to handle a `group` HTTP parameter: https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/src/master/src/http/cervlet.c#lines-2619. But I don't know how to pass that parameter. Passing by query (`?group=xyz`) doesn't work.

Comment: You see groups the service is assigned to in the Webfrontend, but there is no way to query the services are assigned to a group via the group name. The CLI (the monit command) can do this by using "-g" only.

Comment: Check the issues list, this is a requested function but not available yet. Feel free to vote for https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/1007/output-result-not-filtered-by-group-when. A suggestion only.